# Python subprocess command hanging at end of command

Tags: python, git

I have the following code -

```
try:
   working_dir = "/data/mypath/git_repo/"
   os.chdir(working_dir)
   command = "git submodule deinit -f -- *"
   p = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', command])
```

When it runs, it does everything successfully with no errors -

```
Cleared directory 'a'
Cleared directory 'password'
Cleared directory 'plugin'
Cleared directory 'profile'
...
```

But then it clears the last directory, and then just hangs and does not continue on in the Python program.

```
Cleared directory 'profile'

... Continues to hang
```

What gives?  Do I have to do something special with that specific git command?  It works correctly when running it outside of Python.

Comment: is there also a `Popen.wait` call there to check that the subprocess finished?

Comment: You may find `subprocess.check_output` or `subprocess.call` easier to work with for simple cases

Comment: The subprocess.call worked successfully.  If you add that as an answer I'll go ahead an accept it.  Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: why do you call `/usr/bash` and not `git` directly?